# General advice for responsive margins on sections

Tags: css, responsive-design

Im building a responsive site. It basically has `<sections>` that are stacked down the page. Broken up by `<H1,H2>` etc.

I was wondering  really what the best way to set the margins so sections and headers don't appear too close and bunched up. I have tried the following:

1. set the margins using px and then write media queries to adjust as the screen get smaller
2. set the margins using (em) I saw this approach on a video is this even recommended?
3. set the margins using %'s. Again not sure if this is best?

Im getting to a point now where I need to refactor my CSS and make my decision going forward.

Any help much appreciated.
Pete

Answer (score 0):

1. mobile first media queries work the best at the moment as you always have less to do as screen size gets smaller,

so like

```
media screen and (min-width: 320px) {}
media screen and (min-width: 769px) {}
```

1. dont use ems too much, they are relative to their parent layer and if you go too deep in cascading, it's impossible to track down, rem is supported by all browsers now i believe.

   1. % is good for setting width perhaps, i mean margins do not have to be smaller or larger with screen sizes too much i think, but rem with a backup px setting is the best i believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into viewport metadata:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false;">
```

More on Mozilla Developers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag